# doctrine2 mapping required

Tags: mapping, doctrine-orm

I'm newbie in doctrine 2. i want to know which mapping required for doctrine 2?
I create my **Annotation** map with all columns, methods and etc.

I need to know it's required to define **XML** or **YAML** mapping for any kind of features in doctrine 2 and without them which feature i haven't?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use one type of mapping and you've done so already with the annotation approach. This is also the preferred approach from what I gather.

The other mapping methods just let you work the way you prefer. So if you want to have your schema defined away from your model source code. You can use XML or YAML. A lot of the Symfony guys use YAML because it's what the framework is configured with. I personally prefer the annotation method.